# Loop over vector (introspection in R?) or some other approach

Tags: r, loops

I have a table `tf` of values with column headings `formant vowel   length  IL  SG`.

This is how I get their values:

```
f1a <- subset(tf, tf$vowel=='a' & tf$formant=='F1')$IL
f2a <- subset(tf, tf$vowel=='a' & tf$formant=='F2')$IL

f1e <- subset(tf, tf$vowel=='e' & tf$formant=='F1')$IL
f2e <- subset(tf, tf$vowel=='e' & tf$formant=='F2')$IL
```

Is there a way to rewrite this with a loop for a given `vowels <- c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')`? Or is there some other approach?

## A Solution: `split`

By using `split`, the above can easily be achieved by one line only:

`fvowels = split(tf$IL, paste(tolower(tf$formant), tf$vowel, sep=""))`

Where:

- `split` reshuffles data in `tf$IL` according to the second part of the argument;
- `paste` joins items after converting them to `string`;
- `tolower` changes characters to lower case.

The result in `fvowels` is a set of data from `f1a` to `f3u`.

Comment: What are your feelings towards lists?

Comment: List are on my schedule for learning R, thanks for reminding me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `split`

```
tf <- data.frame(
  formant = sample(c("F1","F2"), 100, T),
  vowels = sample(c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'), 100, T),
  IL = runif(100)
)
split(tf$IL, paste(tolower(tf$formant), tf$vowels, sep=""))
```

It gives you named list with separated data. You could `assign` or `attach` it to global workspace if you want it as separated variables, but I recommend using list instead (you could e.g. `lapply` over list or save it easily).

Answer (score 3):

Using this dataset:

```
tf <- data.frame(formant=c("F1","F2"),vowel=c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'),IL=rnorm(100))

vowel<-c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

Then a for-loop would be:

```
for (i in vowel){
    assign(paste("F1",i,sep=""),subset(tf, tf$vowel==i & tf$formant=='F1')$IL)
    assign(paste("F2",i,sep=""),subset(tf, tf$vowel==i & tf$formant=='F2')$IL)
}

F1e
F2a
```

Another option, using plyr:

```
library(plyr)
foo<-dlply(tf,.(formant,vowel),function(x)x$IL)

foo$F1.e
foo$F2.a
```

But split used by Marek is probably the best way to do this:)

Comment: Thanks, Sacha. I run into `plyr` while I was trying to solve the above with `reshape`, but it seemed confusing. I'll try this out as well.