# how can I get the means after splitting the data by columns? statistics with R

Tags: r

thanks for the useful answer in:

[Loop over vector (introspection in R?) or some other approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002707/loop-over-vector-introspection-in-r-or-some-other-approach)

I want to get the mean out of each vector without having to type it for each vector individually. how do i do this?

My code:

```
probability_ratings = split(offline$Probability,
  paste(offline$Item, offline$Cond, sep=""))
head(probability_ratings)

$i01c1
[1] 7 7 7 3 7 3 7 6

$i01c2
[1] 4 4 5 3 4 5 5 3

$i01c3
[1] 7 4 6 4 7 5 5 5

$i01c4
[1] 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 4

$i01c5
[1] 5 5 6 5 7 3 4

$i01c6
[1] 6 6 7 6 7 5 6
```

I need the mean of each row, but I am not sure what data type this is and if/how i can apply the mean() function.

Thanks,
Katerina

Answer (score 7):

`split` returns a list, so you just need to use `sapply` or `lapply` to apply `mean` to each list element.  `lapply` will return a list and `sapply` will return a named vector (in this case).

```
probability_ratings <- list(
  i01c1=c(7,7,7,3,7,3,7,6),
  i01c2=c(4,4,5,3,4,5,5,3),
  i01c3=c(7,4,6,4,7,5,5,5),
  i01c4=c(1,2,2,1,2,2,2,4),
  i01c5=c(5,5,6,5,7,3,4),
  i01c6=c(6,6,7,6,7,5,6) )
sapply(probability_ratings, mean)
#    i01c1    i01c2    i01c3    i01c4    i01c5    i01c6 
# 5.875000 4.125000 5.375000 2.000000 5.000000 6.142857
```

Answer (score 3):

I would go for aggregate(), without using split.
Using the example from your link:

```
tf <- data.frame(
  formant = sample(c("F1","F2"), 100, T),
  vowels = sample(c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'), 100, T),
  IL = runif(100)
)
aggregate(IL ~ formant + vowels, data = tf, mean)
```

but there are also a lot of other possibilities to do that...